# Error trying to import CSV in Leads Module in Vtiger CRM 7.0

Tags: php, crm, vtiger, vtigercrm

We have in trouble trying to import CSV to leads module in CRM 7.0 where there is the message error saying " Unable to import more data in this batch. Please start a new import. "

Any assistance and reply is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have already one import job in queue which is not finished yet.

This import will be done via cron, so make sure you have configured vtiger cron.

There will be only one import job is allowed for a user. So you can import from another user if you want.